# I have an existing AWS RDS Postgres database with JSON and UUDID columns, and I was wondering if there is a simple way to get it to work with Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

Sorry for the dumb newbie question,but I have spent the last two days trying to figure out how to simply get Slick up and running with my existing table.

Below is the Create statement I used to make the Postgres Table, in retrospect I regret having the Json columns since text would have also worked, but I thought JSON was more self documenting. The info and languages column are at this moment meant to be like mini NoSQL stores:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial primary key,
  country_code text,
  city text,
  name text,
  email citext UNIQUE,
  imgurl text DEFAULT 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/canvasmp3/the_default.png',
  photos json,
  user_code uuid  DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  age smallint,
  gender text,
  info json,
  languages json,
  password text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT  current_timestamp,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT  current_timestamp
```

);

build sbt file (keep in mind I am not really sure what half of them do, I just followed any documentation I could find):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"      % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "play-flyway"                   % "1.2.2",
  "com.github.mauricio"  %% "postgresql-async"              % "0.2.+",
  "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.12.1",
  "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_date2" % "0.12.1",
  "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_play-json" % "0.12.1",
  "org.scalikejdbc"      %% "scalikejdbc-async"             % "0.6.+"
)
```

Users.scala file in models:

```
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._ 
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class User( 
   id: Long,
   email:String,
   imgurl:String,
   photos:Option[JsonString] = None,
   age:Option[Int] = None,
   name:String,
   gender:Option[String] = None,
   info:Option[JsonString] = None,
   languages:Option[JsonString] = None,
   user_code:String,
   password: String,
   country:Option[String] = None,
   createdAt: Timestamp, 
   updatedAt: Timestamp
  )


class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id =  column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def age = column[Int]("age")
  def country_code = column[String]("country_code")
  def password = column[String]("password")
  def imgurl = column[String]("imgurl")
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def info = column[JsonString]("info")
  def languages = column[JsonString]("languages")
  def gender = column[String]("gender")
  def photos = column[JsonString]("photos")
  def user_code = column[UUID]("user_code", O.DBType("UUID"))
  def updated_at = column[Timestamp]("updated_at")
  def created_at = column[Timestamp]("created_at")
  def * = (id.?, name, password, country_code, age, email, gender, imgurl, info, languages, photos, user_code, updated_at,created_at) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
 }
```

My biggest issue is I keep finding conflicting information on the web, and the documentation only covers very simple examples such as a table with one String column.

Thank you.

Comment: you could try the slick [codegen](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/code-generation.html) to automatically generate the models from the existing database.

Comment: What's your question exactly? You can make it work with Slick yes, are you having any problems?